# Function not working, argument passing fail

Tags: c++

- Note: It seems the code is not a problem itself, but a linking/compiler problem. The first block of code is in a file called mesorti.cpp. Both the function merge and mesort are there. The command that compiles this is: `g++ -Wall -Wextra -I. -std=c++11 -fpermissive -c -o mesorti.o mesorti.cpp` `g++ -Wall -Wextra -I. -std=c++11 -fpermissive -o 1 main.o mesorti.o`

I have copied the file mesorti.cpp as is.

The following function is supposed to use a vector and then sort it. I have created it so that it *should* sort the vector, and return the time it spent sorting it. But it doesn't return the sorted the array, and the time spent indicates it is indeed not even sorting it. The function itself is indeed working, (it sorts a local array when specified inside the function) so this has to do with argument passing.

This is the function, it is a mergesort algorithm that recursively calls itself and uses another function, *merge*:

```
#include <inc.h>
void merge(vector<int>& array, vector<int>& array1, vector<int>& array2) 
{
    array.clear();

    int i, j, k;
    for( i = 0, j = 0, k = 0; i < array1.size() && j < array2.size(); k++)
    {
        if(array1.at(i) <= array2.at(j))
        {
            array.push_back(array1.at(i));
            i++;
        } else if(array1.at(i) > array2.at(j))
        {
            array.push_back(array2.at(j));
            j++;
        }
        k++;
    }

    while(i < array1.size())
    {
        array.push_back(array1.at(i));
        i++;
    }

    while(j < array2.size())
    {
        array.push_back(array2.at(j));
        j++;
    }
}

double mesorti(intv &array) 
{
    auto t0 =chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    if (1 < array.size()) 
    {
        intv array1(array.begin(), array.begin() + array.size() / 2);
        mesorti(array1);
        cout<<"wola";
        intv array2(array.begin() + array.size() / 2, array.end());
        mesorti(array2);
        merge(array, array1, array2);
    }
    auto t1 = chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    double T = chrono::duration_cast<chrono::nanoseconds>(t1-t0).count();
    return T;
}
```

And this is a portion of **main**:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <chrono>
using namespace std;

typedef vector<int> intv;
typedef vector<float> flov;
typedef vector<double> douv;

double mesorti(intv &vii);

int main()
{
    size_t t;
    int i;
    intv vi;
    cout << "Size: \n";
    cin >> t;
    vi=vectori(0,t);   // This function creates a vector.
    for(i=0; i<t; ++i)
    {
        cout << vi[i] <<"\n";
    }

    time=mesorti(vi);      
    for(i=0; i<t; ++i)
    {
        cout << vi[i] <<"\n";
    }
}
```

But this is not sorting the array, last cout just returns the same array, and I am passing it by reference, Shouldn't it work?

Comment: Please use better variable names as it's hard to tell at a glance what exactly `array`, `array1` and `array2` mean. Making the latter two const references would have helped me understand which are the input parameters more quickly.

Comment: after correcting various bugs in your code it works(i mean sorts) for me, compiled using clang on mac.

Answer (score 2):

There's nothing wrong with your code. Try re-writing your main as:

```
int main() {

    intv vi { 3, 2, 1, 5, 4 };
    size_t t = vi.size();
    int i;
    cout << "Original: \n";
    for(i=0; i<t; ++i) cout << vi[i] << ' ';
    cout << '\n';

    double time=mesorti(vi);      
    cout << "Sorted: \n";
    for(i=0; i<t; ++i) cout << vi[i] << ' ';
    cout << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

If you're still having a problem, maybe you have a linking problem (e.g. linking to an old `.o` file.)

Output:

```
Original: 
3 2 1 5 4 
Sorted: 
1 2 3 4 5
```

Note: For simplicity I'm using C++11-style vector initialization. If you don't have a C++11 compiler, initialize it in some other way.

---

Edit: Here's the full single-file `main.cpp` file which compiles and runs for me:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <chrono>
using namespace std;

typedef vector<int> intv;
typedef vector<float> flov;
typedef vector<double> douv;

void merge(vector<int>& array, vector<int>& array1, vector<int>& array2) {
     array.clear();

     int i, j, k;
     for( i = 0, j = 0, k = 0; i < array1.size() && j < array2.size(); k++){
        if(array1.at(i) <= array2.at(j)){
            array.push_back(array1.at(i));
            i++;
        }else if(array1.at(i) > array2.at(j)){
            array.push_back(array2.at(j));
            j++;
        }
        k++;
    }

    while(i < array1.size()){
        array.push_back(array1.at(i));
        i++;
    }

    while(j < array2.size()){
        array.push_back(array2.at(j));
        j++;
    }
}

double mesorti(intv &array) {
auto t0 =chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
if (1 < array.size()) {
    intv array1(array.begin(), array.begin() + array.size() / 2);
        mesorti(array1);
        intv array2(array.begin() + array.size() / 2, array.end());
        mesorti(array2);
        merge(array, array1, array2);
    }
auto t1 = chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
double T = chrono::duration_cast<chrono::nanoseconds>(t1-t0).count();
return T;
}

int main() {

    intv vi { 3, 2, 1, 5, 4 };
    size_t t = vi.size();
    int i;
    cout << "Original: \n";
    for(i=0; i<t; ++i) cout << vi[i] << ' ';
    cout << '\n';

    double time=mesorti(vi);      
    cout << "Sorted: \n";
    for(i=0; i<t; ++i) cout << vi[i] << ' ';
    cout << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Well, I have tried and it is not working... I thinks it is indeed a linking problem. I am using a Makefile to compile the project, I will investigate it.

Comment: The first block of code is in a file called mesorti.cpp. Both the function merge and mesort are there. The command that compiles this is: `g++ -Wall -Wextra -I. -std=c++11 -fpermissive -c -o mesorti.o mesorti.cpp ` `g++ -Wall -Wextra -I. -std=c++11 -fpermissive -o 1 main.o mesorti.o`